# android statusbar color is seen blue before changing to another color

Tags: android

I wrote a code to change the color of the status bar, using a Java code as follows:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#d3d6db"));
    }
```

And again through the xml as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#d3d6db</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In both cases, when the application starts, the status bar appears blue and changes to the color i selected.When a program such as WhatsApp starts, the status bar is green and stays the same, how is it done?

Comment: perhaps it's a lifecycle issue?  like you are calling .setStatusBarColor too late... when a lifecycle method that is called earlier could be used?

Comment: I thought about it and I tried all the methods in the life cycle, even threads with and without the method join

Comment: Are you sure that it's not simply that the action bar is blue... and it is stretching under/overlapping the status bar area?

Comment: yes,I am very sure

Comment: The color of the status bar appears in its natural color before it changes

Comment: That is because you aren't creating/using your own `ToolBar` you use the Theme toolbar, which will have it's theme colour until your `window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#d3d6db")` code is called.  Use a `Theme` that has no `ToolBar` and create your own that gets inflated with `setContentView(..)` - you can customise your `Toolbar` through the `xml`..

Comment: sounds like a legit answer

Comment: I do not have one, and I did as you said,nothing happened

Comment: `I do not have one, and I did as you said` - If you have done it correctly then your problem will be solved as the there will be no need to programatically do anything with window flags, and the `Toolbar` with only ever be one color - the color you set it as - https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html, also if you want to target values for different api levels just create `values-vXX` folders with the relevant changes to the default `values` items.

Comment: Should I have one to complete my work?

Comment: what is the value of `@color/colorPrimary` ?!! is it `#d3d6db` ?

Comment: and why you not adding         `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>`

Comment: because  
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
The reason lies in the manifest file where it should contain

```
android:minSdkVersion="the minimum version supports changing the status bar color"
```

When the version is selected then the status bar color will be the selected one when the program is started

Answer (score 0):

Try including

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/your_theme_color</item>
```

under `AppTheme` in your `styles.xml`.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found the solution.